# Outlier detection and removal using scatter-plots and histograms

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, naive-bayes-classifier, outlier

Suppose, we use the following code to generate scatter plots,

```
function res = plot2features(tset, f1, f2)
% Plots tset samples on a 2-dimensional diagram
%   using features f1 and f2
% tset - training set; the first column contains class label
% f1 - index of the first feature (mapped to horizontal axis)
% f2 - index of the second feature (mapped to vertical axis)
% 
% res - matrix containing values of f1 and f2 features

    % plotting parameters for different classes
    %   restriction to 8 classes seems reasonable
    pattern(1,:) = 'ks';
    pattern(2,:) = 'rd';
    pattern(3,:) = 'mv';
    pattern(4,:) = 'b^';
    pattern(5,:) = 'gs';
    pattern(6,:) = 'md';
    pattern(7,:) = 'mv';
    pattern(8,:) = 'g^';

    res = tset(:, [f1, f2]);

    % extraction of all unique labels used in tset
    labels = unique(tset(:,1));

    % create diagram and switch to content preserving mode
    figure;
    hold on;
    for i=1:size(labels,1)
        idx = tset(:,1) == labels(i);
        plot(res(idx,1), res(idx,2), pattern(i,:));
    end
    hold off;
end
```

The following is its usage,

```
>> plot2features(train, 3,4)
```

This code generates the following image before removing outliers,

[image]

and following image after removing outliers,

[image]

---

**I have the following questions,**

(1) **What do the 1st image tell us about the existence of outliers?** I can guess that the plot at a distant position is an outlier. But, how can I find which row or column is generating outliers? according to the 1st picture, the outlier is situated at (27,375) coordinates. But, in the actual data it is situated on the `train(184:188,:)` rows. So, why is that difference?

(2) **What do the color codes in the second picture represent?**

(3) **Why has the two images that much different?** Why only removing 4 rows bring so radical differnce?

(4) **How can we analyze the existence of outliers using histograms?** Please, supply me any study material about outlier detection using histograms.

---

Suppose we have the following training and test data in our hands to be used in testing Bayes Classifier algorithm,

**Training data**

[train.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVqTx5Vp2gjSkRTdUdFVk55TzQ)

**Test data**

[test.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVqTx5Vp2gjNU1vLXFodU9Sakk)

First column represents class. Rest of the columns represent features.

---

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. This code does nothing but to plot the points for two chosen columns and assign different color and markers to them. It does not do any outlier selection/removal.
2. Column 3 and 4 (which are features in your dataset) are reasonably predictive of different classes.
3. Plot a histogram. See if there is any clear disjoint in among the bars. Investigate a little time to find a suitable bin size.

In addition, the title of your question does not match the content. Can you please update the question?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, histograms will give you an idea about where your outlier is by (as mentioned previously from other users) displaying bars which are disjointed from others by a reasonable distance. You may have to play around with the bin-widths to discover it, but it should be noticeable.

Another tool that may be useful to you is the box-plot. This visualization will not only give you information about the distribution of the data (though, unlike the histogram, frequency won't be specified), but will also specifically identify outliers. I would recommend using a combination of the scatter-plot, histogram, and box-plot to better familiarize yourself with your data.

I'm uncertain if MATLAB has this functionality (though I image it would), but in R when you plot your data you can choose to display the index of each observation above the data point on scatter-plots. Digging into MATLAB's plot function a bit more couldn't hurt.